# Fundamental Y86 : Documentation and basic requirements

Tags: assembly, y86

I have the following *very* simple Y86 program in file `foo.ys`:

```
irmovl $1, %eax
```

Running the following command:

```
$ yas foo.ys
```

I get the following (utterly useless) feedback from `yas`:

```
Invalid Line
```

So--I have a few questions:

1. Where does the Y86 documentation live?
2. What is invalid about the above program?

Comment: 1. google, for example [y86tutoring](https://y86tutoring.wordpress.com/y86-ia/)  2. nothing, works here.

Comment: Mainstream (real) architectures might be more complicated, but they often have better toolchains that give (slightly) more useful error messages.  Assembler error messages are often pretty vague, but not *that* vague.

Comment: @Jester - What version of yas are you using?

Comment: I downloaded [this one](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~bradykey/sim341Student.tar), it has no version number.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the 64 bit version, y86-64. I have checked, that in fact produces the given error message. While x86-64 does support 32 bit, apparently y86-64 doesn't. You should use `irmovq $1, %rax` instead (note the change of instruction suffix and register prefix).

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919423/y86-instructions-set-create-confusion

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Y86 is *supposed* to be a subset of the IA-32, [whose documentation can be found here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/253665-sdm-vol-1.pdf).

It seems, in IA-32, move instructions ending in `l` don't move long data types; they do conditional moves and things irrelevant to Y86.

Yet, some versions of Y86 support `irmovl`, some don't.

If you're using a 64-bit version of `yas`, use quadword instructions and addresses:

```
irmovq $1, %rax
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a 64 bit version. Those use quadwords, but then your register should be `rax` not `eax`.

Comment: @StudentsTea: it's IA-32 (Intel Architecture), not AI.  Not my downvote, but this answer isn't really useful and you should probably delete it.  (It also has errors.  x86 doesn't have `movl`, you're thinking of `cmovl`.)  Intel x86 docs aren't really useful for y86.  Maybe AT&T-syntax docs would be, but with y86 or y86-64 only supporting a fixed operand size (or maybe also byte?) real x86 manuals would just be confusing.